Why String can't be returned from a method with return type <T extends Comparable<T>> T?
Given that
    public final class String
        implements java.io.Serializable, Comparable<String>, CharSequence,
                   Constable, ConstantDesc {
    ...

Why a String return is not valid?


Because I may request a Dog. And a String is not a Dog.

Please read: Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?

The only thing you can return safely from that method is null, because that's the only thing that can always be cast to whatever the caller expects.

You may not request a Dog because the method has no way for you to input that, so the output is only up to the method to decide, not the caller.

probably "request a Dog" was meant to be something like Dog aDog = getValue(); - in this code, the compiler will infer T as being Dog

For what purpose might such a method be useful?

It would be useful to provide each parameter for method
 private <T extends Comparable<T>> int compare(T v1, T v2, boolean reversed) {   return reversed ? v2.compareTo(v1) : v1.compareTo(v2);  }
for which that same definition works well, BTW

You misunderstand what this means. You apparently think it means: "T is anything that is a Comparable or some subtype of it".
This is incorrect. after all, that concept is represented by... Comparable<String> itself.
No, you read this stuff as 'unknown':
public void <T extends Comparable<T>> T getValue() { ... }
means:
"There is an unknown type. The caller knows what it is, but this code does not and cannot possibly figure it out. All we know is, the caller picked it, every caller can pick a different one, and, whatever choice was made, it's at least a subtype of Comparable<T>."
Your code must work such that it is valid for all possible choices any caller could make.
That sounds impossible, and indeed it is - unless you know the trick. Which is, that generics link things. The trick to returning a thing of a type you don't know, is to get it from the caller, which does know. Here is a trivial example:
public <T> T print(T in) {
  System.out.println(in);
  return in;
}

In this example the same unknown happens: T is an unknown type; the caller knows it, you don't and can't know it. Nevertheless, this code is valid for every possible choice the caller could make, because what you return is something you got from the caller in the first place.
If you want to write a method that returns String just.. write public String getValue() {return "hola";}. With that, you can assign it to anything that 'works'. For example:
Comparable<String> str = getValue();

This works - but is kinda useless here (just assign it to a variable of type String; all String values are also Comparable<String>; any method that requires a Comparable<String> can be passed a string and it'll work.
NB: There are situations where you write a method that has a type param which is used in only one spot - the return type, however, these methods always fall into one of these categories:

They get around not knowing what to return by literally always ending in return null; - because null is every type at once, and therefore, necessarily compatible with T even if we have no idea what T is.
They get around not knowing what to return by never returning. while (true) ; is one way to do it. Always ending in throw new SomeException(); is another. if you never actually return a value, then it's no problem that your method should return a value of an unknown type, which is impossible.
They hack it with an ugly cast: return (T) something;. This generates a warning, because, the compiler has no idea. It's just going by your word that things will work out. If they don't, and why should they, you end up with ClassCastException errors on lines that have no casts in them. Bad idea - confusing code is bad, confusing errors are worse.


Thanks for your detailed reply @rzwitserloot  What I was trying to represent is: return something which is comparable with something else of the same class (but not related to the input). How should that be written?

You can't express that with generics as far as I can tell.

You may try public Comparable<?> getValue(). It doesn’t specify what type the returned object is comparable to. In practice it will nearly always be a related type.
